# Does group policy loopback apply to that policy, or all policies?

Tags: group-policy

Does group policy loopback processing apply to that policy that it is defined in, or all policies applied to that container?

For example, assume there are 2 group policy objects: one has loopback processing enabled and the other does not. Both policies contain user settings, and are applied to a computer container.

Which policies will be applied? Both? Or just the policy that has loopback processing enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loopback processing mode is a computer configuration and has effect on the target computer (don't forget that this setting ends up in the computer's registry)

It's not a per-GPO setting, the usual priority/precedence of GPOs are still valid here. If GPO n°1 has loopback processing enabled, you don't need to enable it on other GPO for computers that are in the scope of GPO n°1.

You can learn more about loopback processing by reading this blog post: [Circle Back to Loopback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/circle-back-to-loopback)

Comment: Thank you. I struggled to find an article that described it as clearly as the one you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:** How Loopback Policy work in Replace and Merge Mode for Compuer Configuration and User Configuration settings in GPO

In Active Directory User & Computer we have one user LondonUser in LondonUsersOU and we have PC1 inside DevEnvironmentOU  as below

[image]

Now We have GPO applied at OU level as below

[image]

In all GPO I am setting both Computer Configuration and User Configuration where I am appending debug text `<GPO Name>` to some Environemnt Variable. After User Logs-In We will check the value of this Environment variable to see GPO execution order.

[image]

Now when you restart the PC1 and login as LondonUser the policy are executed in below order

[image]
[image]

**Case-1: Replace Mode**

[ In this mode LondonUserGPO is never executed and instead (User Settings) in GPO'S inside DevEnvironmentOU are executed]

[image]

Now when you restart the PC1 and login as LondonUser the policy are executed in below order

[image]
[image]

**Case-2: Merge Mode**

[ In this mode (User Settings) inside LondonUserGPO is executed and are merged with (User Settings) in all the GPO'S inside DevEnvironmentOU]

[image]

Now when you restart the PC1 and login as LondonUser the policy are executed in below order

[image]